# MongoDB being interacted with through monk returns differing values upon document removal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoskin, monk

I am interacting with a MongoDB using the module `monk`.

Working locally, everything is operating as expected. However, I've pushed the app to Heroku, and something has been changed that is causing errors however I can't ascertain exactly what.

One thing I've noticed is that when I hit a delete endpoint I've created, which maps to the db.collection.remove method, when I hit the endpoint locally I receive a `1` in response from monk.

However, when I hit the API endpoint as it's hosted on Heroku, the response is:

`{
  "ok": 1,
  "n": 1
}`

Is monk using a new version of `mongoskin` one of its dependencies? I've looked through the modules thinking that may be the case, but haven't been able to determine anything.

What has changed that is causing the db.collection.remove() method to return different values?

Answer (score 1):

Remove method is depreciated if you are using the latest version of mongoskin as it uses version 2 of the mongodb driver underneath.  The method has been replaced by deleteOne and deleteMany, see [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#remove) for more info, also the return value from method is described [within the mongodb driver docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#~writeOpCallback)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's close to what was happening. I was using mongoskin version 1.x.x locally but Heroku had cached mongoskin 2.x.x and was using that, thus the difference in API output, because like you've alluded to the API is a bit different.